# Firestore Firebase Document Bundles High Document Reads

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, bundle, cdn, firebase-extensions

I'm using Firestore and have recently incorporated the [Firebase Document Bundles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/official/firestore-bundle-builder) extension. I've set it up via CDN, and it's working well except for one issue: high database reads. I notice that every few hours, there's a new query for the bundle, accumulating to over 1000 document reads.

I have set the bundle to expire every 24hrs on the CDN and client side.

**Questions**:

1. Does this mean that a new query is executed every time someone from a different geographical location accesses the Firebase Document Bundle, causing it to be recreated?
2. Is there a way to generate the bundle once and share it across different geographical locations to minimize database reads?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!